# Saving a parking spot and legal recourse

Tags: civil-law

I have seen others, and may have once or twice, stepped into an open parking spot to "reserve it" for my friend who is coming by, say within a minutes.

- What laws if any are those "saving a spot" breaking?
- What recourse does the blocked driver looking for an open parking spot have?

Answer (score 2):

An officer could cite a pedestrian for obstructing traffic **if** they're in the traffic lanes. But if they are only in a parking spot, that is unlikely to apply.

An officer might cite them for loitering or creating a public nuisance. But that would require an officer to observe the behavior and be unable to resolve/diffuse it by talking to the pedestrian.

I am not aware of anything the blocked driver could do, short of calling an officer, and hoping the officer shows up before the "friend", which seems highly unlikely.

Comment: Well the blocked driver can just sit there and block the friend from getting the spot as well. At that point a fight will likely break out and then the officer would have different charges to sort through.